# Disable noise messages in debug output windows - visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

How do I disable messages in the debug output windows of visual studio 2012?

> The thread '' (0x2360) has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Since the count of such messages is so high they bother me and hide my custom debugging information written using `Debug.Write`. Should I highlight my custom debugging information using red instead?

Answer (score 136, accepted):

Right click on the `Output` window for the `Debug` selection; here you can select which types of messages to see.

The `Thread Exit Messages` option will be disabled in the example you gave.

[image]

Answer (score 23):

You can can also get to these settings at any time by searching in the Quick Launch bar (Top Right of VS) and search for "Output Window". This will bring up the settings for the Output Window regardless of the Output Window's current context.

[image]