# Suppress "The thread 0xb40 has exited with code 0 (0x0)."

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, output

I am debugging a javascript / C# /ASP.NET / SignalR program in visual studio. In the output window the message

`The thread 0xb40 has exited with code 0 (0x0).`

Suddenly appears one or more times [the `0xb40` part changes]. This is annoying because the part of the output I am looking at suddenly jumps a few lines and I lose track of where I am.

Is there some way of suppressing the message?

Answer (score 0):

Perfect answer by Maxim [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720599/disable-noise-messages-in-debug-output-windows-visual-studio-2012?rq=2). I just unticked `Thread exit messages` on the pop up menu in the output/debug window. Thanks!